# Find Unique Values In Column from Worksheet with Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have autofiltered a worksheet and am trying to establish the unique values within the filtered data. I feel like I have the correct approach, but the my results only show 2 of the possible 8 unique values.

```
Private Sub GetAllCampusDomains(DomainCol As Collection)
    Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long, i%, lastrow As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       
    'Clear the previous filter
    shtData.ShowAllData
    
    'Filter the data
    shtData.Range("A:Y").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=shtSetup.Range("CampusName") 'SchoolName
    shtData.Range("A:Y").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="DomainPerformance" 'ColI
           
    'Inspect the visible cells in ColP
    lastrow = shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).row
    data = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'Find the unique values
    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
    Next
    data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys())
    
    'Walk through the unique values
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        Debug.Print data(i, 1)
        'DomainCol.Add data(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The error seems to have to do with this line:
data = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

This call only seems to create a 90x1 sized array, when it should be much bigger.

I greatly appreciate your help!
Josh

Comment: You guessed right. You cannot write the values of a non-contiguous range to an array in this way. You should do `Dim rng as Range: Set rng = shtData...` and then decide between looping through the cells of the range and writing to the dict or looping through the areas and writing to several arrays (in one array) and then looping through those arrays and writing to the dictionary. Or change the whole approach i.e. copy the complete range to an array and then filtering with if statements etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, replace this piece of code:

```
data = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'Find the unique values
    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
    Next
```

with the next one:

```
    Dim rng As Range, C As Range
    Set rng = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'Find the unique values
    For Each C In rng.cells
        dict(C.Value) = Empty
    Next
```

Your initial code iterates between the first area range cells.

The second one will iterate between all visible range cells...

Comment: By using `P1` instead of `P2`, the column header is also written to the dictionary.

Comment: @VBasic2008. Yes, you are right. I made some tests and I forgot to adapt it... The idea was that, being a matter of **only one column**, such a way works and it is simpler against iteration between the range areas...

Comment: @FaneDuru: But you are also writing `independent of being visible or hidden` by which you mean hidden included which is not true because `SpecialCells` in this case ensures only visible cells.

Comment: @VBasic2008. Yes, I say that... If you iterate in a non contiguous range using `i`, even if the row is not inside the visible cells range, it will be taken in consideration and iteration will not reach the last range rows. I mean, the range between two consecutive areas. Test that, please ... Take a discontinuous range ("A2:A4, A6:A10") and iterate from 2 to  9. Use `Debug.Print rng(i, 1).Address`... A5 address will appear.

Comment: @FaneDuru: When you use `Data = rng.Value` and `rng` is a non-contiguous one-column range then only the first area is copied to `Data` making it a 2D one-column array if there was more than one cell (in the first area of the range). If there was one cell only then 'Data' will not be an array. It will just contain the value of the only cell (in the first area of the range).

Comment: @VBasic2008: You are right. I mixed ranges with arrays... I will delete/adapt my pseudo "explanation"...

Comment: Terrific answer @FaneDuru. It works perfectly. Great insights in the comments too from all of you. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

### Non-Contiguous Column Range to Jagged Array

Instead of...

```
data = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Find the unique values
For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
Next
```

...use the following...

```
Private Sub GetAllCampusDomains(DomainCol As Collection)
    
    '...
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = shtData.Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    getNonContiguousColumn Data, rng
    
    'Find the unique values
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(Data)
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data(j))
            dict(Data(j)(r, 1)) = Empty
        Next r
    Next j

    '...

End Sub
```

...backed up by the following:

```
Sub getNonContiguousColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                           NonContiguousColumnRange As Range, _
                           Optional FirstIndex As Long = 0)
    
    Dim j As Long
    j = FirstIndex - 1
    ReDim Data(FirstIndex To NonContiguousColumnRange.Areas.Count + j)
    
    Dim ar As Range
    Dim OneCell As Variant
    ReDim OneCell(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    For Each ar In NonContiguousColumnRange.Areas
        j = j + 1
        If ar.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            Data(j) = ar.Value
        Else
            OneCell(1, 1) = ar.Value
            Data(j) = OneCell
        End If
    Next ar
    
End Sub
```

Test the previous Sub with something like the following:

```
Sub testGetNCC()
    
    Const rngAddr As String = "A2:A20"
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(rngAddr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    getNonContiguousColumn Data, rng

    Dim j As Long, i As Long
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(Data)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data(j))
            Debug.Print Data(j)(i, 1)
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```